# Links not active in CSS-only toggle-down hamburger menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, toggle

I've created a CSS-only toggle-down hamburger menu for cellphone browsers.

The links in the menu are not active, they're not clickable. I suspect it's some kind of opacity problem. The menu can be seen in Codepen. Here's the link:

```
<http://codepen.io/martincol/pen/ZePKab>
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Martin

Comment: The issue is that you're using margin-top and absolute positioning - the click is actually captured by the .puppies div. Try going to relative positioning with the transition on the max-height of the nav.

Comment: I haven't been able to make this method work. Brian, please show me the code changes that make the links active.. Thanks, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is negative `z-index` value. This change will fix your issue.

```
.verticalNav {
    top: -135px; /* changed */
    z-index: 0; /* changed */
}
```

#### Update:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    color: #111;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.overlay > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    left: 185px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 16px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

.overlay > label::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
}

.verticalNav {
    color: #333;
    position: relative;
    top: -55px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 130px;
    font-size: 22px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ddd;
    transition: top 600ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}

.verticalNav a {
    display: block;
    color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.verticalNav a:hover {
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.puppies {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 115px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: margin-top 600ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
}

img {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 115px;
}

#toggle {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .verticalNav {
    top: 80px;
}

#toggle:checked  ~ .puppies {
    margin-top: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
    <label for="toggle"></label>
</div>

<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle">
<div class="verticalNav">
    <a href="www.nytimes.com">NEWS</a>
    <a href="/">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="/">BLOG</a>
    <a href="/">CONTACT</a>
</div>

<div class="puppies">Puppies love pure CSS code</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-8.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: This makes the links active. But the menu no longer slides down from below the hamburger. It now slides down from the top of the main div. Z-index of -1 is needed to put the menu behind the hamburger div.

Comment: It's so easy, you just increase the `z-index` value for `.hamburger` and the `label` as well: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqXBZL

Comment: I've increased z-index to 1 for hamburger and label. Links still not active. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MartinColes Did you view my codepen link abow? Is this your expected?

Comment: This is not quite what I wanted. With my version, menu slides down from beneath the hamburger and its div. With your version, menu slides down from the top of the hamburger and its div. If possible, I want to maintain my version, but with active links.

Comment: @MartinColes I'm updated my answer, I hope it fix your requirement. Your primary problem still structuring and styling your elements.. you're killing yourself by using over complicated structure and negative `z-index` value.